# get auto_increment value from mysql to jtextfield in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jtextfield

i have created a two column in mysql

```
Category    varchar(30) YES         
Serial_No   int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
```

how to retrieve Category column using Serial_No in mysql and set this category data in Jtextfield in java.

Comment: so basically: "how do I select data from database" - that is **far** too broad.

Comment: @luk2302  It is and auto_increment column and how to get a specified column using auto_increment value

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

In your Java Swing code,

Connect to MySQL using the corresponding Driver.

`Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection (hostname:port/db_name, user, password)`

Step 2:

Write the query to fetch the required detail. In your case, the query will look like,

> select Category from table_name where Serial_No='your_value'

Step 3:

With the Connection object, create an instance of Statement.

`Statement mysqlStatement = yourConnectionObject.createStatement ( )`

Step 4:

Execute the query with the help of Statement

`ResultSet rs = mysqlStatement.execute (query)`

Step 5:

Iterate ResultSet, get Category and assign it to JTextField.

`while (rs.next ( ))
{
   String category = rs.getString ("Category")
   JTextField myTextField = new JTextField (category); // or if you have already a text field, then myTextField.setText (category); this setText ( ) method is inherited from JTextComponent
}`

Step 6:

Once everything is over don't forget to make your frame visible.

`myJFrame.setVisible (true)`

Comment: Serial_No='your_value' this is an auto_increment column and how to get that serial_no

Comment: `public void Update()
 {
  try
  {
  Category=textField_2.getText();
  
  query="Update Category_Table Set Category='"+Category+"' where Serial_No='"+Serial_No+"'";
  PStat=con.prepareStatement(query);
  PStat.execute();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Updated Data");
  Category_List();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }`

Comment: You should either pass the serial_no as an argument or store the serial_no in some field and take it out just like you did with Category (stored in textField_2)

Answer (score 0):

my answer: i have to update that specific category using serial no which is auto_increment column in mysql. so i find my solution Thank You

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                Row=table.getSelectedRow();
                TableModel model=table.getModel();
                Category=model.getValueAt(Row, 0).toString();
                Serial_No=model.getValueAt(Row,1).toString();
                textField_2.setText(Category);
            }
        });

public void Update()
    {
        try
        {
        Category=textField_2.getText();

        query="Update Category_Table Set Category='"+Category+"' where Serial_No='"+Serial_No+"'";
        PStat=con.prepareStatement(query);
        PStat.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Updated Data");
        Category_List();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```